# Loading a video file using emgucv 2.1.0.0

Tags: c#, video, emgucv

I need to know how to **load** a **video file** using **emgucv** 2.1.0.0 in C#. I just need some guidance. I also need some guidance on how to use the emgucv API(I have one documentation which came with the installation), so I dont have to keep asking questions when I can find it already in the API(***NOTE:*** For instance, I went through a video on you tube to learn how to use the java API and now pretty comfortable using it, could not find one for emgucv). For example, I find methods for different things but I have no clue to apply them in code.

Perhaps a method and how to use it might be helpful.

Thanks so much

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you've imported the Emgu DLLs correctly, load your video file using

```
Capture capture = new Capture("filename");
```

Then you can grab frames from it using

```
Image<Bgr, byte> img = capture.QueryFrame();
```

You can view the image with the ImageViewer-class:

```
ImageViewer viewer = new ImageViewer();
viewer.Image = img;
viewer.ShowDialog();
```